# Alternative of GetGlobalAsaxType in .NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

I am checking out a sample application source code and there is:

```
var assembly = BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType().BaseType.Assembly.GetName().Name;
```

But in .NET 3.5, there is no BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType(). Is there any alternative way to do so in .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType()` instead of `BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType()`?